# In DacFX, Can I exclude messages that are for excluded objects

Tags: c#, sql-server, dacpac

I am using DacFX to compare and create a script between to SQL Server databases.

After running the compare I go over the changes and exclude some due to internal functionality.

After I finish excluding the objects I run `SchemaComparisonResult.GetErrors()` and print out the warnings and errors.

Some of the errors are for objects that were excluded and I don't want to display them as they are no longer relevant.

Is there a way to do that without going over the content of the message as messages might vary and I can't reference all of the in my code

Edit:

I tried doing exclude in 2 ways:

Before running compare:

```
                List<TSqlObject> sourceModel = TSqlModel.LoadFromDatabase(sourceConnectionStringBuilder.ConnectionString).GetObjects(DacQueryScopes.UserDefined).ToList();
                List<TSqlObject> targetModel = TSqlModel.LoadFromDatabase(targetConnectionStringBuilder.ConnectionString).GetObjects(DacQueryScopes.UserDefined).ToList();
                TSqlObject sourceObject;
                TSqlObject targetObject;
                foreach (var exclude in preExcludeProp)
                {
                    sourceObject = sourceModel.FirstOrDefault(o => string.Join(".", o.Name.Parts) == exclude.ToString());
                    targetObject = targetModel.FirstOrDefault(o => string.Join(".", o.Name.Parts) == exclude.ToString());
                    if (sourceObject != null)
                    {
                        comparison.ExcludedSourceObjects.Add(new SchemaComparisonExcludedObjectId(sourceObject.ObjectType, new ObjectIdentifier(sourceObject.Name.Parts.ToArray())));
                    }
                    if (targetObject != null)
                    {
                        comparison.ExcludedTargetObjects.Add(new SchemaComparisonExcludedObjectId(targetObject.ObjectType, new ObjectIdentifier(targetObject.Name.Parts.ToArray())));
                    }
                }
```

After running compare:

```
                foreach (SchemaDifference diff in results.Differences)
                {
                    string name = string.Join(".", (diff.SourceObject ?? diff.TargetObject).Name.Parts);
                    if (postExcludeProp.Contains(name))
                    {
                        results.Exclude(diff);
                    }
                }
```

Both had the same results

Compare: SchemaComparisonResult results = comparison.Compare();

Getting the errors: results.GetErrors()

Comment: Please put a snapshot of how you are excluding and doing schema compare